# why the alignment break when i used selector in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

Hi,
I am using selector in radio button , but my layout break.can you please tell me how to remove that bug.I use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:stretchColumns="2" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF00" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Eligibility confirmed:" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/eligibility"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/eligibilityYes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/redio_yes_selecetor"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="yes" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/eligibilityNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"

                    android:text="No" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

=====================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_checked="true"/>
```

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>][2]


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#AFA7EF"
        android:gravity="center"
      >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Obtaining Informed Consent Form"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp" 
           />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to assign the `weight` to both your `RadioButton` to `android:layout_weight=".25"`

Comment: please check my update..question

Comment: Now it look like this ..test is not visible

Comment: Please post your `@layout/header` code .

Comment: Which test is not visible ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46936/discussion-between-user1542984-and-grishu)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the equal `weight` to both your `RadioButton` to `android:layout_weight=".25"` as you have weight of `0.5` to your `RadioGroup`.

Try out below code

```
     <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/eligibility"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/eligibilityYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:background="@drawable/redio_yes_selecetor"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="yes" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/eligibilityNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="No" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

[image]

If you want to set the text on the left side then you need to make the button property to `@null`
and you have to set the `drawable` image of `RadioButton` on the right side and text on the left side.